# Messaging Menu missing after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: messaging-menu

Upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 today, and the messaging menu is missing. Might be because the only application that I use with the messaging menu is Pidgin. Is this an issue where pidgin has not been integrated with 12.10 ?

I am assuming here that the messaging menu is hidden when no application is using it.

What can I do to integrate pidgin with the messaging menu and get it back ?

Answer (score 7):

The way applications interact with the messaging menu was changed in 12.10, and not all applications have been updated. Pidgin (as of 20th Oct 2012) has not been updated. There is a [ticket tracking](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1040259) what applications have been migrated. Until then Empathy could be used as an replacement.

Answer (score 3):

The messaging menu (normally in the top right) is turned off by default in 12.10. Simply open the "Broadcast preferences" application and check "Start service at login" to get it back.

in 12.10 Pidgin has been replaced with Empathy, so you may have to set it up.

Comment: ,,where ist the broadcast pref??

Comment: A screenshot here would be great!

Comment: Hit super/windows key to open the unity menu and type broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

There's a patch available for pidgin-libnotify on a ppa [here](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/gnome3).

To add it, open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
```

After you've entered your password, press enter and observe that the signing key matches 6E3AB2D3. Then update and install the patched package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-libnotify
```

If all went well when you start pidgin you should see notifications in the messaging menu.