# Gm-notify back on messaging icon on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, email, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Messaging Menu missing after upgrade to 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201664/messaging-menu-missing-after-upgrade-to-12-10)

I use gm-notify to receive notifications of when i receive an email.

How do i get the messaging icon back on the panel to see how much emails i have?
(curently using gm-notify and not using online accounts)