# Message indicator for liferea missing in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, messaging-menu, liferea

How do I get back How to get back message indicator for liferea in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/203636/99763) should answer your question:

[indicator-messages has been updated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1040259), and the api has changed, liferea is on the list in triage. Not sure when an update may come through, but guys who can fix it, know about it.

Comment: Ditto for LightRead as well...