# Messaging menu integration for Thunderbird does not work in Ubuntu 12.10 anymore

Tags: thunderbird, messaging-menu

Since I have updated to 12.10 the Messaging menu integration for Thunderbird does not work anymore. What am I supposed to do? Does anybody else has experienced this problem? Which components are necessary for Thunderbird to work with the message menu generally?

That means I have the Messaging menu but neither Evolution nor Thunderbird show up there as they did before:
[image: Messaging Menu without Thunderbird]

Comment: You are right, I mean the Messaging menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found out, what was the problem: I had an old Thunderbird extension for Ubuntu installed:  Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher Integration
This Extension is not supported anymore. After I completely removed it (don't deactivate but remove it!) everything works as expected again.

Answer (score 3):

I think the memenu only is disabled, turning it On in the broadcast menu, look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201664/messaging-menu-missing-after-upgrade-to-12-10).

I think it helps you.

EDIT:

I've the package `thunderbird-globalmenu` installed (for a long time...)

In thunderbird you have to change some preferences maybe

In the german version look at the following:

Bearbeiten -> Einstellungen -> Allgemein -> Im Nachrichtenmenü anzeigen (check)

and maybe check "Für Nachrichten in allen Ordner"

in englisch I think the preferences are something like

Edit -> Prefernces -> Global (Menu on the left side) -> Show in Messaging Menu (check)

and maybe check "For all folders"

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed with thunderbird 17.0.3 and I can see new messages in the menu and get a blue icon

Comment: The memenu was deprecated in 12.10.

Comment: What is the "broadcast menu"? I am seeing the  Messaging menu. But neither Evolution nor Thunderbird show up there as thy did before.

Comment: Edited my answer to setting up thunderbird correctly for messaging menu.

Comment: My settings are as you propose, but it doesn't work at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your thunderbird open, while getting a mail?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a few days, then worked out that in:

Thunderbird > Add-ons > Extensions

Make sure that 'Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher Integration 1.3.1' add-on is installed **and** enabled.

Now my 'Mail' indicator icon functions correctly.

Comment: Where to find that extension?

Answer (score 0):

Install `thunderbird-globalmenu` package, which includes the messagingmenu extension.

Comment: I have that package already installed. Thank you anyway.